How to start one Linux container from another?
On Chromebook Crostini Linux I can (via .ssh/authorized_keys) stop one
container from another,
jidanni@n1:~$ ssh n2 sudo shutdown -h now

But starting it requires
 crosh> vmc start termina
(termina) chronos@localhost ~ $ lxc start n2

or click Terminal App, then click n2.
How can make a script that will do that typing or clicking for me?
(Without voiding my warranty.)

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/platform2/+/refs/heads/main/vm_tools/vmc/vmc.rs#1028
